# Close with Custom Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, air, adobe

I'm using Adobe Air with a custom chrome and want to have a close button to close the window

I'm just starting out so I have no idea. I'm using HTML and javascript with Aptana Studio.

Comment: What that "close button" should do?

Comment: I want it to close the window, sorry should have said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.nativeWindow.close();
```

with jQuery

```
$('a').click(function(){
    window.nativeWindow.close();
});
```

[More info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e08.html)